# use of join command to edit file contents in perl

Tags: perl

I'am doing the following operation to edit a particular line in a file and send the whole contents to another file after editing.

the contents of my input file is:-

```
;first set
00 01 05 10 10 11 22 55 66
;second set
00 00 00 01 10 11 11 11 11 
;third set
00 01 05 10 ff 11 22 55 66
;fourth set
00 00 00 01 10 11 11 11 11
```

In the row after the third set, fifth element `ff` I want to replace with `5f` and the pass the whole contents of this file to another file.

I have written the code which replaces the fifth element with `5f` but the next row as well gets concatenated with the edited row in the output file.

the output file is as follows

```
;first set
00 01 05 10 10 11 22 55 66
;second set
00 00 00 01 10 11 11 11 11 
;third set
00 01 05 10 5f 11 22 55 66;fourth set
00 00 00 01 10 11 11 11 11
```

```perl
my $parameter = "third";
my $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
my $outputfile = "Extract"."_".$inputfile;
my $check = 0;

open(INPUT, "<$inputfile") or die $!;
open(OUT, ">$outputfile") or die $!;

while (<INPUT>)
{
    if($check == 1)
    {
        my $line = $_;
        my @chunks = split ' ', $line;
        $chunks[4] = "5f";
        $check = 0;
        print OUT join (" ", @chunks);
    }
    else
    {
        print OUT $_;
    }

    if($_ =~ m/$parameter/gi)
    {
        $check = 1;
    }
}

close(OUT); 
close(INPUT);
```

Comment: please note that first set is first line of the file and 00 01 05 10 10 11 22 55 66 is the second line and so on..

Comment: Output file has 00 01 05 10 5f 11 22 55 66;fourth set   in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `split ' ', $line` command removes *all* whitespace — including newlines — from the string, leaving only the data. It is the same as `my @chunks = $line =~ /\S+/g`. So you have to add a newline back after you print it.

This is how I would code a solution

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $parameter = 'third';
my ($inputfile) = @ARGV;
my $outputfile = "Extract_$inputfile";

open my $in_fh,  '<', $inputfile  or die $!;
open my $out_fh, '>', $outputfile or die $!;
select $out_fh;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
  print;
  if ( /$parameter/ ) {
    my @chunks = split ' ', <$in_fh>;
    $chunks[4] = '5f';
    print "@chunks\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
;first set
00 01 05 10 10 11 22 55 66
;second set
00 00 00 01 10 11 11 11 11 
;third set
00 01 05 10 5f 11 22 55 66
;fourth set
00 00 00 01 10 11 11 11 11
```